# Enable CORS for any port on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

in asp.net core i can use middleware to enable CORS on certain methods as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

i want to know if its possible to enable CORS for any scheme and any port on `localhost` ( for testing purpose only). i tried wildcard and it does not work

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        if(_environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
              options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                 builder =>
                 {
                     builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost/*",
                                         "https://localhost/*");
                 });
             });
        }
        else
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                 builder =>
                 {
                     builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                         "http://www.contoso.com");
                  });
             });
        }

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

ASP.NET Core's [`SetIsOriginAllowed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.setisoriginallowed) method gives you full control over whether or not an origin is allowed to participate in CORS. Here's an example based on your code sample:

```
if(_environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).Host == "localhost");
    });
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

The `origin` value passed in to the `SetIsOriginAllowed` delegate is the full origin, which looks something like `http://localhost:8080`. Using [`Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netcore-2.2), the code above compares the [`Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.host?view=netcore-2.2) against `localhost`, which ends up allowing all `localhost` origins.

Comment: I also needed to add `.AllowAnyHeader()` and `.AllowAnyMethod()` to the builder policy on my Web API.

Comment: You can also use `new Uri(origin).IsLoopback` instead of checking `new Uri(origin).Host == "localhost"`.

Comment: Is there a way to use this in conjunction with `.WithOrigins()`? When I've tried, `.SetIsOriginAllowed()` overrides any other origins I've specified beforehand and only allows ones that match the conditional.

Comment: @HarrisonPaine You can't combine those two methods, but you can do anything you like inside of `SetIsOriginAllowed`, which could `||` with something like `YourOrigins.Contains(origin, StringComparer.Ordinal)`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin sure, but [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.withorigins?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Cors_Infrastructure_CorsPolicyBuilder_WithOrigins_System_String___) for `.WithOrigins()` mentions "This method normalizes the origin value prior to adding it to Origins to match the normalization performed by the browser on the value sent in the ORIGIN header." which makes me think it's doing more than a simple comparison.

Comment: @HarrisonPaine Here's the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/5.0/src/Middleware/CORS/src/Infrastructure/CorsPolicyBuilder.cs#L55-L97) to show exactly what `WithOrigins` is doing for you.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Where is `_environment` and `options` is coming from?  Is it from the Builder? Can you add this to your explanation?

Comment: `_environment` is available as `builder.Environment`

Comment: @Tamb, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#inject-iwebhostenvironment-into-the-startup-class explains where `_environment` comes from, except it uses `_env`. `options` is just using the name LP13 used in his example code.

Comment: Dotnet Core 7.0 and above may have it like this:

if(app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{

    builder.Services.AddCors();
    app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).IsLoopback));
}

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an older post and the examples above did not work for me.

Following [this guide on Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0) it worked.

My Example localhost (React front end calling .NET Api). See the blocks marked CORS. The original with port localhost:5174 is the React site on localhost.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {

    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    //CORS-----------------------------
    var specificOrgins = "AppOrigins";

    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: specificOrgins,
                          policy =>
                          {
                              policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5174");
                          });
    });
   //CORS-----------------------------


    var app = builder.Build();

    //CORS-----------------------------
    app.UseCors(specificOrgins);
    //CORS-----------------------------


    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    app.UseAuthorization();            

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I'm currently using this for testing and it works, if you take the wildcard off yours should work.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost");
            });
        });



        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
   }
```